# Quadrilateral with maximum area inside a semicircle

Tags: geometry, optimization, circles, area, quadrilateral

The quadrilateral $ABCD$ inside a semicircle with radius 1 has a maximum area. Calculate  that maximum area.
Clues to solution  include the observation that the vertices of such quadrilateral must be on perimeter of semicircle.

Comment: If this is a puzzle that you already have a solution for, wouldn't Puzzling.SE be more appropriate?

Comment: You could reflect the answer in the diameter to give a simpler question

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote to reopen this. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Comment: @Martin How many words are required to explain an elementary geometry-for example- problem in your opinion?  How many words should be used to explain the Author's work on it????!!!!

Comment: @HamidRezaEbrahimi It's less about explaining the parameters of the problem and more about explaining why you want to solve it. Is this a.) a textbook problem you're looking for help on, b.) something you're casually researching and exploring, c.) something you're posing as a challenge to the community, or d.) something else?

Comment: Option a doesn't seem like what you have in mind, but it's probably the most common category of questions on here. Option b could work, you'd just need to state that that's the context of the question. Option c, as I said, would probably be more appropriate for Puzzling.SE. Option d, it'd help to explain the context that you have in mind for this.

Comment: @Dylan , Thank you so much for your detailed explanation, from now on I do know it's not a good idea here to ask a question that I already know the answer and this community is not interested in it

Comment: Re: *it's not a good idea here to ask a question that I already know the answer.* This is certainly not true. If you take some time and look at some post I mentioned [on meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/22624/why-mark-as-off-topic-without-a-convincing-reason-lack-of-rationality-in-t#comment88894_22624), you will see that such posts are ok. (Although some users have mixed feeling about them.)

Comment: As I have already mentioned, the first edit after the question was put on hold will put it into [reopen review queue](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/16821), where users will vote whether it should be reopened. Some suggestion which could improve your post: You can replace "I will give a complete solution soon." by saying that you have already posted your solution. (I think that this should qualify as including " your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made", which is part of the definition of context. Another reasonable thing to do could be adding some tags. ...

Comment: ...Certainly some of the tags ([tag:quadrilateral]), ([tag:circle]), ([tag:area]), ([tag:max-min]) would fit this question. Adding source of the problem would be good, too. Of course, I cannot guarantee that your post will be reopened, but this would at least give it a chance.

Comment: @MartinSleziak, Thank you so much,I really appreciate your guidlines.I didn't know these things.

Comment: It's not clear to me, though, what the point is of posting a question to which you know an answer. If your actual question is, does anyone know a proof that's better than the one I'm posting, then that's what you should ask. If you're not actually asking a question, well, consider starting a blog, instead.

Comment: @GerryMyerson My impression (from the many discussions on meta on this issue) is that in general it is ok to make a post whose only purpose is solely to make some result available on math.SE. (I have certainly made a few such posts.) I will add link to a few links to such discussions, the views on this type of posts seems to range mostly from mixed to positive. (Of course, it is not advised to make too many such posts by the same user. In such case, blog would certainly be a more suitable medium, as you suggested.)

Comment: Here are some links (which did not fit to the previous comment due to character limit). There are probably some other related posts on meta.
[Questions whose answers are known to theOP](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1839),
[Views on asking and answering questions solely to make results available on stack exchange](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4337/),
[Recently rolled out SE Encyclopedia feature](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4286/),
[Posting a question that was solved before being post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5039/).

Comment: @Martin, fine, though I think if someone's going to do that, he/she should give a clear indication in the body of the question that that's what's up.

Comment: @MartinSleziak "My impression (from the many discussions on meta on this issue) is that in general it is ok to make a post whose only purpose is solely to make some result available on math.SE. ... Of course, it is not advised to make too many such posts by the same user. ..." This would also be roughly my own summary of what I read on meta on the subject--and frankly I have no idea how the second part is even logically compatible with the first part. Am I missing some point?

Comment: @Did I am afraid I do not understand your last comment. Perhaps we could move this discussion [to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/19138/2016/2/19), so that we do not make here many comments which are not about this question but about a general issue concerning this type of posts.

Comment: @MartinSleziak The point is that if some practice is allowed one usually does not limit this practice.

Comment: @MartinSleziak The story continues: some other people recently put this question ON-HOLD again,despite deleting the BAD SENTENCE and doing the corrections you suggested!!

Comment: @Hamid Reza Ebrahimi: the reason that I voted to close is that the current state of the question is quite bad. Please expand and revise it significantly, to include the motivation for the problem, why it is of interest, etc.   Questions for which the OP already knows the answer, and just wants to post it on this site, need to be of the highest quality, which does not describe the current state of this post.

Comment: @CarlMummert At least you explained your reason for voting down,thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we note that all of the vertices of such quadrilateral must be on perimeter of semicircle:
[image]

For triangle $ABC$ having maximum area implies that B must be right in the middle of arc $AC$ (to have a maximum height).Similarly arcs $BC$ and $CD$ should be equal.
Suppose that the angle of arc $AB$ is $\alpha(0\le\alpha\le\frac{\pi}{3})$. Then

$$\begin{split} 
S(ABCD) &=S(AOB)+S(BOC)+S(COD)-S(AOD) \\
&=3S(AOB)-S(AOD)\\
&=\frac32\sin(\alpha)-\frac12\sin(3\alpha)\\
&=\frac32\sin(\alpha)-\frac12(3\sin(\alpha)-4\sin^3(\alpha))\\
&=2\sin^3(\alpha)\\
&\le 2 \sin^3(\frac{\pi}{3})\\
&=2(\frac{\sqrt 3}{2})^3\\
&=\frac{3\sqrt3}{4}
\end{split}$$
So the maximum area of such quadrilateral inside a semicircle is $\frac{3\sqrt3}{4}$.

Comment: If someone believes an answer has low scientific value , at least he/she should provide a better one.

Comment: Ah, we may be approaching the source of your misunderstanding. Scientific value is NOT the only factor users take into account when deciding how to vote. You are not the only user who has been surprised by the fact that people's views of what the site should be about also affect their voting. There are several heated discussions in Meta around this theme. BTW, a nice way of reasoning! I figured this out when I was training for IMO about 35 years ago, so it's a bit old hat for me. Surely some youngsters will benefit from reading this.